# How to preprocess and correctly include scss in angular component + webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I am configuring webpack to build my angular application.
Now I am stucked, how to preproccess scss and include it in the angular component.

In the component, I am referencing scss directly.

[image]

In the webpack I have loaders for scss and css.

[image]

Webpack output is building into dist folder. But in dev-tools I see, that it's trying to include directly this app.component.scss file

[image]

Could you please help me to move forward with this issue? What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any kind of hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my webpack.config.js. It works fine

```
module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
            { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "to-string-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                    }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|woff|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 105000, // if less than 10 kb, add base64 encoded image to css
                            name: "assets/[hash].[ext]" // if more than 10 kb move to this folder in build using file-loader
                        }
                    }]
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env', 'react-app']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/, use: [
                    {
                        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
                    }]
            },
        ]
    },
```

I just included my CSS in my root component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./../styles/app.scss']
})
```

It works as Expected. Try it and let me know

Comment: It's still trying to find the dist/app.component.scss file.. :( But it should be part of the js bundle, if I am correct

Comment: Can you create a plunker with your code so that I can have a look ? and can you check where you have referenced your scss file...